# How to switch between two digital signals?

Tags: digital-logic, switches, multiplexer, signal-processing, switching

How can I switch between two PWM signals? I would like to control a servo motor by two different PWN source. these two PWN signals are coming from two PID controllers.

I want to switch between these two signals by an Arduino. here is a schema of what I want to do, but the problem is that I can't find the right switch. 
what do you suggest? 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use...

- [MUX](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT153.pdf) (multiplexer). The selection inputs control which one of the inputs gets sent to the output. Simple.
- [Tri-state buffers](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT125.pdf). Connect the outputs together, and enable only one buffer at a time.
- [Analog switches](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC4016.pdf)... Well, they are switches, they will let the signal through when closed, quite self-explanatory
- Junk parts solution with bipolar transistor used as common base switch

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faUXih.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: thanks dear peufeu, I'm working by analog switch 4066. it works good when enable leg is directly connected to 5 volt by  wire, but when I use the Arduino digital pins for ON and OFF, it doesn't work well, and always is ON

Answer (score 2):

There might be better ways than the one I just thought of since I'm only a hobbyist, but you could have an AND gate on each PWM output, with your PWM signals on one input and a 'toggle' signal on the other input. Since an AND gate needs both inputs high to turn its output high, there will be no output without the 'enable' signal. To make sure when one is on, the other one is off, we can use a not gate before the second AND. Finally, we need a XOR gate avoid the mistake I made earlier: a state where one AND outputs hi and the other low. This would cause a short circuit as pointed out in the comments bellow.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f92t8R.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Are you sure you want to connect the outputs of the two AND gates together?

Comment: Yep, this won't work. Just use a multiplexer.

Comment: Educate me please. To me it seems only one of them can be on at once.

Comment: What if AND1 outputs a 0, and AND2 a 1?

Comment: I think I got you. Current from AND2 to AND1?

Comment: Yeah. You need something with a tristate output that includes HiZ.

Comment: That complicates things a bit then :/

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out guys. I think I fixed it now.

Comment: Why would you need a XOR gate?  Why not just an OR gate?

Comment: That was my 1st thought. I already knew there wouldn't be a spate with both ANDs ON because of the NOT gate but I thought you never know, if that happens it's going to be because of some failure so I might as well have the out OFF.

Comment: thanks dears, I'm very thankful of your answer and attention. logic gates are my second choice, for now I'm trying to get answer by analog switches or maybe MUX. thanks again